# Setting properties transport and path for socket.io

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to create the socket connection with the backend over the socket.io library.
Thing is - I need to turn off the long-polling option and set the custom path. But I can't set them both because always work only one option.
So, if I try this way, I'm setting the `path`, but not `transports`:

```
this.socket = io(
  'wss://some-url.com',
  { path: '/v1/url/to/websockets' },
  { transports: [ 'websocket' ] }
);
```

And library is trying to make the long-polling connection that will be rejected by the server (which I don't have access to), but path will be correct.
But if I'm trying to change the order and set the `transports` property first, library will omit the `path` property and frontend will send the request to the 
`wss://some-url.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket`
url, which is incorrect.
I understand that it is some conflict because of the fact that `transport` property changes the URL (it sets itself as the query param), but what I don't understand - how can I set the path and transports properties because I need them so bad.
Didn't find the solution on the official docs and here.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your synatx is wrong, correct syntax

```
 this.socket = io(
                 'wss://some-url.com', 
                 { 
                    path :'/v1/url/to/websockets', 
                    transports: ['websocket']
                 });
```

i.e. both should be within same object

Comment: In that case call this.socket.connect(); won't make the connection

Comment: Just checked, like I said, code this.socket.connect() doesn't make any moves, I don't see the "handshake" request, I don't get the "onconnect" event (of course), etc.

Comment: With above code, client is connected to your socket server. Why are you calling this.socket.connect() after that?? Regarding handshake as Iwebsocket transport is used there will be only one http request with response as 101. After that at my end on connect event is getting called properly.

Comment: As I understand I can call .connect() method manually. But never mind, I don't see the "GET" socket request (I mean, handshake) in the console anyway

Comment: Hmm... Wait, looks like it works now. Interesting. So the answer above is correct, I need only find the difference, why it didn't work before...